# bash shellcheck issue with variables in brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion, shellcheck

I'm trying to create an array of file names, based on two variable and using brace expansion, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
altdir=/usr
arg=abc
tries=({.,$altdir}/{$arg,$arg/main}.{tex,ltx,drv,dtx})
for i in "${tries[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

The last statement list the files I want correctly:

```
./abc.tex
./abc.ltx
./abc.drv
./abc.dtx
./abc/main.tex
./abc/main.ltx
./abc/main.drv
./abc/main.dtx
/usr/abc.tex
/usr/abc.ltx
/usr/abc.drv
/usr/abc.dtx
/usr/abc/main.tex
/usr/abc/main.ltx
/usr/abc/main.drv
/usr/abc/main.dtx
```

But shellcheck tells me that the two variables, altdir and arg, appear to be unused:

```
$ shellcheck testscript

In testscript line 3:
    altdir=/usr
    ^-- SC2034: altdir appears unused. Verify it or export it.

In testscript line 4:
    arg=abc
    ^-- SC2034: arg appears unused. Verify it or export it.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems as a shellcheck's bug. They seem to fail to recognise a variable usage in brace expansion.

Comment: I think you're fine. An unused variable warning is meant to catch typos; if you know you aren't making a mistake, it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: @WyboDekker shellcheck's [commit history](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/commit/6076f0b1daabc55915ffe2de888c4604ebdab815) suggests that this was fixed in 0.3.8. Your version 0.3.4 is over a year old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround can be:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset altdir
unset arg

: "${altdir:=/usr}"
: "${arg:=abc}"

tries=({.,"$altdir"}/{"$arg","$arg"/main}.{tex,ltx,drv,dtx})
for i in "${tries[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

or make `shellcheck` ignore `SC2034` code:

```
shellcheck -e SC2034 testscript
```

(And remember to always [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906) if you don't want list context)

Comment: Thanks! After all I found that the online version of shellcheck behaves differently than my Debian-8.1 version (shellcheck-0.3.4). The online version had no problem with my original script, except for the $i that should be quoted. The Debian shellcheck said about the quoted tries= statement: "Use spaces, not commas, to separate array elements. [SC2054]", which is why I removed the quotes.